# Take a Pandas Series where each element is a DataFrame and combine them to one big DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series where each element of the series is a one row Pandas DataFrame which I would like to append together into one big DataFrame. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
mySeries = pd.Series( numpy.arange(start=1, stop=5, step=1) )

def myFun(val):
    return pd.DataFrame( { 'square' : [val**2],
                           'cube' :  [val**3] } )
## returns a Pandas Series where each element is a single row dataframe
myResult = mySeries.apply(myFun)
```

so how do I take `myResult` and combine all the little dataframes into one big dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mySeries = pd.Series(np.arange(start=1, stop=5, step=1))


def myFun(val):
    return pd.Series([val ** 2, val ** 3], index=['square', 'cube'])

myResult = mySeries.apply(myFun)
print(myResult)
```

yields

```
   square  cube
0       1     1
1       4     8
2       9    27
3      16    64
```

Comment: was just about to post very similar....fyi, you function could return the column labels as the index of the function series, e.g. ``pd.Series([val**2,val**3,index=['square','cube'])`` will work as well

Comment: @Jeff: Ah, much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html#pandas.tools.merge.concat) them:

```
In [58]: pd.concat(myResult).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[58]: 
   cube  square
0     1       1
1     8       4
2    27       9
3    64      16
```

Since the original indexes are all 0, I also reset them.

Comment: You can also do `pd.concat(myResult, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Its seems overly complicated, although you probably posted a simplified example. Creating a new Series for each row creates a lot of overhead. This for example is over 200 times faster (for n=500) on my machine:

```
meResult = pd.DataFrame({'square': mySeries**2,'cube': mySeries**3})
```

Comment: your intuition is correct. My example is a bit of an extreme simplification.